# Show the selected value in a form

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli

How can I put the selected value in a variable and show it in a another form ?

[image]

Code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nih_bw");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select name from pools");
echo "<form action='' method='POST' ><select name='mypool'>";

$default_name = "foo_bar"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $opt_name = $row['name'];
  $str_selected = "";
  if($opt_name == $default_name){
      $str_selected = "selected";
  }
  echo "<option value='".$opt_name."' ".$str_selected." >" . $opt_name. "</option>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>";
echo "</select></form>";
mysqli_close($con);




if (isset($_Post['submit']))
{

echo $_POST['mypool'];

}
```

Comment: Assign it to a variable and then echo it ?

Comment: is the other form on another page?

Comment: echo "Chosen: ".$str_selected; This didn't work.

Comment: So you should create a helper function that creates your `select`.

Comment: Why did you delete the other question and asked over?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$default_name = "foo_bar"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $opt_name = $row['name'];
  if($opt_name == $default_name){
     echo "<option value='".$opt_name."' selected='selected'>" . $opt_name. "</option>"; 
  } else {
     echo "<option value='".$opt_name."'>" . $opt_name. "</option>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Just use a form tag and post it,

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nih_bw");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select name from pools");
echo "<form action='ANOTHERPAGEURL' method='POST' ><select name='mypool'>";

$default_name = "foo_bar"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $opt_name = $row['name'];
  $str_selected = "";
  if($opt_name == $default_name){
      $str_selected = "selected";
  }
  echo "<option value='".$opt_name."' ".$str_selected." >" . $opt_name. "</option>";
}
echo "</select></form>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And use this in another page,

```
<?php
echo $_POST['mypool'];
?>
```

Hope this works

Comment: If i do it on the same page, i will change the action to "", but then I get: Undefined index: mypool in

Comment: Just check whether the form is posting properly. If not make the form to post by a button or some JS stuff like on change event. It will work fine

Comment: Also just check if(isset($_POST['mypool'])) {echo $_POST['mypool'];} This will work.. this will avoid the Undefined error.

Comment: See edit code, that didn't work for me. I cant get anything out when I press submit.

Comment: Put this code after closing the </select>... echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>";.. then close the form..

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a `<form>` and post it.

try this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['mypool']))
   echo "Value is: " . $_POST['mypool'];

echo "<form method='POST' action='#'>";
echo "<select name='mypool'>";

$default_name = "foo_bar"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $opt_name = $row['name'];
  $str_selected = "";
  if($opt_name == $default_name){
      $str_selected = "selected";
  }
  echo "<option value='".$opt_name."' ".$str_selected." >" . $opt_name. "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='send' />";
echo "</form>";
```

if you want to handle the post on another page just replace `action='#'` with `action='yourPage.php'` and move this code there:

```
if(isset($_POST['mypool']))
       echo "Value is: " . $_POST['mypool'];
```